# Sanity/next slug- 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, next.js, slug, sanity

When I try to access my slug page, the name of the slug shows in the browser search bar (so I know its accessing the backend data), but nothing shows up on the page. In the console, error 404 keeps coming every 3 seconds.

Due to lack of timing, experience, knowledge, etc., I've had to switch from react to next very last minute (learning both for the first time at the moment). In react, I remember you could establish a path/page that went '/pageName/:slug', but I haven't seen that for next. I *think* this might be what is causing the issue, that I don't have an equivalent of that, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. How do I fix this issue?

I'm happy to post any code if needed.

Comment: Can you share url from the browser?

Comment: Sure: its "http://localhost:3000/sets/solo-sketches" when I click on the solo sketches category, "http://localhost:3000/sets/solo-paintings" for a different category, etc. /sets/ is a .js page I have, and the rest is the unique slug

Comment: Please provide your `pages` folder structure, and the code for the page you're trying to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I hadn't given much context in the post, but I had two .js page files, gallery.js (where I can select a set), and sets.js where I wanted the slug to route into. So my link in gallery.js looked like this: `<a href="./sets/[slug]">`.

The fix: I renamed sets.js to [slug].js, and removed /sets/ so that it was just `<a href="./[slug]">`.